# Unable to issue identity with fabric composer

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I successfully deployed a business network to hlfv1 beta and am now trying to issue an identity for a participant but receive the following error:

```
composer identity issue -p hlfv1 -n 'manumachines-network'
 -i Org1PeerAdmin -s DJY27pEnl16d -u dxid1 -a "org.acme.manumachinesnetwork.Designer#designer-X@email.
com"

Error: fabric-ca request register failed with errors [[{"code":400,"message":"Authorization failure"}]
]
Command failed.
```

Using LoopBack, I know that the participant is on the Blockchain:

```
[
  {
    "$class": "org.acme.manumachinesnetwork.Designer",
    "email": "designer-X@email.com"
  },
  {
    "$class": "org.acme.manumachinesnetwork.Designer",
    "email": "designer-Y@email.com"
  },
  {
    "$class": "org.acme.manumachinesnetwork.Designer",
    "email": "designer-Z@email.com"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out - in the issue identity cli command you must use the id and password of the CA which is found in the:
fabric-tools/fabric-scripts/hlfv1/composer/crypto-config/docker-compose.yml file which is admin and adminpw.

I was erroneously trying to use the admin identity that I had registered as the prerequisite for deploying the network definition.

Comment: Correct. PeerAdmin is used to deploy only. Thanks for posting your solution!